# Wordpress EasyAdmin remove option to edit items

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

The wordpress theme that I am using has an EasyAdmin option for users who are not the administrator, so that they may edit their listings on the site. However, each user role has specific options of their listings that they can or cannot change. For instance, the `directory_1` and `directory_2` user roles should not be able to edit their listing at all, but the `directory_3` user role has full ability to edit their listing. 
What I am trying to accomplish is how can I set it to where certain user roles can edit their listing, and the others cannot?

Snipped of easy-admin.php:

```
function aitDirCreateRoles() {

global $current_user, $aitThemeOptions;

// directory items capability
$capabilityType = 'ait-dir-item';
$capabilitiesAdmin = array(
    "edit_{$capabilityType}" => true,
    "read_{$capabilityType}" => true,
    "delete_{$capabilityType}" => true,
    "edit_{$capabilityType}s" => true,
    "edit_others_{$capabilityType}s" => true,
    "publish_{$capabilityType}s" => true,
    "read_private_{$capabilityType}s" => true,
    "delete_{$capabilityType}s" => true,
    "delete_private_{$capabilityType}s" => true,
    "delete_published_{$capabilityType}s" => true,
    "delete_others_{$capabilityType}s" => true,
    "edit_private_{$capabilityType}s" => true,
    "edit_published_{$capabilityType}s" => true,
    "assign_dir_category" => true,
    "assign_dir_location" => true
);

// set admin capability
$adminRole = get_role( 'administrator' );
foreach ($capabilitiesAdmin as $key => $value) {
    $adminRole->add_cap( $key );
}

$subscriberRole = get_role( 'subscriber' );
$subscriberRole->add_cap( 'directory_account_update' );

// update user roles from admin
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'update' && strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'options.php') !== false){
    $optionName = $_POST['option_page'];
    if(isset($_POST[$optionName]) && isset($_POST[$optionName]['members'])){

        $prefixName = '';
        $options = $_POST[$optionName]['members'];
        $roles = $GLOBALS['wp_roles']->role_names;

        $capabilitiesDirectory = array(
            "edit_{$capabilityType}s" => true,
            "read_private_{$capabilityType}s" => false,
            "edit_published_{$capabilityType}s" => true,
            "delete_{$capabilityType}s" => true,
            "delete_published_{$capabilityType}s" => true,
            "assign_dir_category" => true,
            "assign_dir_location" => true,
            "read" => true,
            "upload_files" => true,
            "directory_account_update" => true
        );

        if(isset($options['role1Enable'])){
            remove_role( 'directory_1' );
            $caps = $capabilitiesDirectory;
            if(!isset($options['role1Approve'])){
                $caps["publish_{$capabilityType}s"] = true;
            }
            add_role( 'directory_1', $prefixName . $options['role1Name'], $caps);
        } else {
            remove_role( 'directory_1' );
        }

        if(isset($options['role2Enable'])){
            remove_role( 'directory_2' );
            $caps = $capabilitiesDirectory;
            if(!isset($options['role2Approve'])){
                $caps["publish_{$capabilityType}s"] = true;
            }
            add_role( 'directory_2', $prefixName . $options['role2Name'], $caps);
        } else {
            remove_role( 'directory_2' );
        }

        if(isset($options['role3Enable'])){
            remove_role( 'directory_3' );
            $caps = $capabilitiesDirectory;
            if(!isset($options['role3Approve'])){
                $caps["publish_{$capabilityType}s"] = true;
            }
            add_role( 'directory_3', $prefixName . $options['role3Name'], $caps);
        } else {
            remove_role( 'directory_3' );
        }

        if(isset($options['role4Enable'])){
            remove_role( 'directory_4' );
            $caps = $capabilitiesDirectory;
            if(!isset($options['role4Approve'])){
                $caps["publish_{$capabilityType}s"] = true;
            }
            add_role( 'directory_4', $prefixName . $options['role4Name'], $caps);
        } else {
            remove_role( 'directory_4' );
        }

        if(isset($options['role5Enable'])){
            remove_role( 'directory_5' );
            $caps = $capabilitiesDirectory;
            if(!isset($options['role5Approve'])){
                $caps["publish_{$capabilityType}s"] = true;
            }
            add_role( 'directory_5', $prefixName . $options['role5Name'], $caps);
        } else {
            remove_role( 'directory_5' );
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: sorry for that, it is updated

Comment: No prob. I was also interested in who's calling `aitDirCreateRoles()`. But reading your question again and analyzing the code, looks like it's not the part you need to change. Because the capabilities being assigned to directory 1, 2 and 3 are ***exactly the same***, in `$capabilitiesDirectory`.